# SUP element and rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I'd like to add rounded corners to `sup` element and some paddings.

```
<div>Here is my main text<sup>sup text</sup></div>
<style>
  sup {
    background-color:#f00;
  }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HPzuZ/

`sup` element have `display:inline;` by default. I can set `display:block;` and manipulate with padding and rouded corners, but I should modify HTML structure because `sup` is block now. Is it possible to decorate `sup` with paddings and rounded corners without modifying HTML structure, but just CSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can apply `inline-block` - http://jsfiddle.net/HPzuZ/1/

```
sup {
    background-color: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0 6px;
}​
```

Comment: Never know about `inline-block` value. Live and learn. Thank you!

Comment: I tried and it worked without `display: inline-block;` just the same. I'm using chrome. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HPzuZ/2/)

Comment: @menislici Yes it will work without the `display` property in FF and Webkit, but not IE. You need it just for that sucker

Comment: Hmm, I thought I had seen that word before (popper) in some online tutorial thinking it meant (figuratively) some type of party crasher (anoying guy, you know), but after seeing the explanations on urban dictionary after your reply I was like *ohgodwhy*. So, pooper it is.